# 数式で2つの列をつなげて1列にする。

Tags: excel

教えてください。
エクセルのA列とB列にいくつかデータが入っていて（可変長：それぞれMAX100個）
C列に「A列の後ろにB列をつなげたもの」が入るように数式を書きたいのですが
どのように書けばよいでしょうか。
数式はあまり長くならないほうがありがたいです。

例

A1:aaa
A2:bbb
A3:ccc
B1:あああ
B2:いいい
B3:ううう
B4:えええ

なら

C1:aaa
C2:bbb
C3:ccc
C4:あああ
C5:いいい
C6:ううう
C7:えええ

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

空行がない前提ですが、こんな数式はどうでしょう。

```
=INDEX(CHOOSE(IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:A),1,2),A:A,B:B),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:A),ROW(),ROW()-COUNTA(A:A)),1)
```

---

追記：
もっと単純な別解ができたので、こちらで解説します。

```
=INDEX(A:B,IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:A),ROW(),ROW()-COUNTA(A:A)),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:A),1,2))
```

ポイントはINDEX関数になります。
A列とB列の値を列数と行数を指定して取得しています。
例えばINDEX(A:B,2,1)なら"bbb"、INDEX(A:B,3,2)なら"ううう"という具合です。
A列を取得するだけでしたら、INDEX(A:B,ROW(),1)で十分です。

しかし途中でB列に切り替える必要があるので、もうひと工夫加えます。
COUNTA関数でA列の行数を取得し、IF関数でA列の行数を超えたらB列から取得するように切り替えます。
IF関数を抜いたB列を取得している処理は、INDEX(A:B,ROW()-COUNTA(A:A),2)のようになります。

つなげる列数が増えるとこの方法では難しくなってしまいますが、今回は問題を解くには十分と判断しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
なにやら複雑な式で理解が追いつかないですが、確かに正しく動いてます。
大雑把に言ってC列のセルに対して自分の行番号がA列の最後の行番号を越えているかどうかで場合わけですかね。

Comment: @Jogenara はい、その理解で問題ありません。